# Centos how to set default permissions for specific folder

Tags: linux, centos, unix, centos5

I have a centos server that one of my apps creates files in a tmp folder. The files are always created with the permissions r--r--r-- and i need all the new files in this directory to be created with at the least, the permissions rw-rw-rw-.

How can i achieve this?

**EDIT**
Here's my current setup. I've chmod 777 everything in the /page folder. Then when i run something in my app, it creates or modifies files and they are not rw-r--r--.

/page

```
ls -ald
drwxrwsrwx 2 tomstest psacln 12288 Aug  2 20:32 .
```

/page

```
ls -al
-rw-r--r--  1 tomstest psacln     2 Aug  2 20:32 size
-rwxrwxrwx  1 tomstest psacln     5 Jul 20 16:58 version
```

My app errors I think because of the line that is rw-r--r--.

Comment: NEVER `chmod 777`. Is `tomstest` the user that your app is running as?

Comment: Yes I think it is.

Comment: Is there a good way to check what user the app is running under? It's a rails app if that's relevant.

Comment: Actually it might be running as root. The reason it's set to user `tomstest` is because i chown'd/chgrp'd/chmod'd the entire folder.

Answer (score 1):

`umask` can help but DON'T do this. Why did you want to give other user the write (w) permission?

Comment: Because the app needs to add and delete files and it bombs when deleting those tmp files.

Comment: What do you mean "bombs"? Why not 664?

Comment: My app throws an error because it can't delete the file. 664 would probably work too.

Comment: What error? Which user your app is running as? Who is owner of those tmp files?

Comment: It's an error in my rails app. Permission denied is the error.

Comment: Question updated with some more details.

Answer (score 1):

I think everyone else is doing a great job of providing answers, but there's one wrinkle that hasn't been addressed.  You specifically mention that your app has a problem when deleting files, but then focus entirely on the protection mode of the files themselves.  You should be aware that **the ability to delete a file under Unix** isn't dependent on the owner or protection mode of the file itself, but of the **ownership and protection mode of the directory the file is in**.  Don't overlook that when seeking the answer to this question!

Comment: Interesting...I was not aware of this. I'll have to check the owner of the directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
umask 0
```

Append the command to your ~/.bashrc file to make it permanent.